# show messages of drupal_get_form loaded forms in custom module

Tags: 7, status-messages

In my case I use drupal_get_form in my custom module in order to load forms from other modules and show them combined in one page (menu callback). So in my custom module I have

```
  function mymodule_claim_menu() {
    $items['profile_edit/%user/%'] = array(
    'title' => 'Edit profile',
    'page callback' => 'connections',
    'page arguments' => array(1,2),
    'access callback' => TRUE,  
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'file' => 'node.pages.inc',
    'file path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'node'),
  );
 return $items;
}

function connections($account,$tab = "profile") {
  $link_output = array();
  $rss_output = array();

  $link_output['linkedin_settings']= drupal_get_form('linkedin_user_enable_form', $account->uid);

  $rss_output['rss_input'] = drupal_get_form('activitystream_accounts_form', $account);

  $output = array_merge($link_output,$rss_output);

  return $output;
}
```

The (simplified) code above works fine except status messages (drupal_set_message) not getting displayed when a user submits one of the forms. I realise from the previous posts that it's something with the order but I'm not sure what I can change to make it work. Any suggestions?

Comment: What kind of status message do you expect and what  (which part of the code) produces it?

Comment: After submitting the 'linkedin_user_enable_form' the user should authenticate to linkedin, get back to the site (works) and see a drupal status message saying that he succesfully added his linkedin account (doesn't work).

Comment: Could you add the code that calls drupal_set_message() or point us to it on http://www.drupalcontrib.org ? I think the source of your problems is outside the code in your question.

Comment: I'm adding in inside the linkedin_access_token function of linkedin.inc of the linkedin module right after the user creation stuff (http://cgit.drupalcode.org/linkedin/tree/linkedin.inc?h=7.x-1.x&id=e48d39ffa7857c88789a82e287471b78e3ff292e I'm adding it after line 126 and before the drupal_goto).

Comment: it was template related after all. Thanks for your interest, I've posted the solution below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting the solution in case anyone else faces the same issue.

This was finally related to the template file. 
The messages were printed in a section that was not rendered when inside my module page. This tricked me because doing it as admin was actually showing the relevant section but for registered users didn't.

So I just had to add an extra printout of the $messages var in a section of the template that was always rendered to all users.